# How to set my own field value as @timestamp? (Logstash)

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, filebeat

i'm trying to set @timestamp whit my own field value but i have only bad results, with tags "_dataparsefailure". I'm newbie and i don't know what i wrong. Someone can help me? (Sorry for my bad english, i'm italian :) )

2021-06-22 09:06:59,041 -----> this is my datatime format

and below there is the code

```
     filter {
        
        ...... (some disssect) ....
        
        aggregate {
     task_id => "%{breadcrumbId}_%{ID}"
     code => '
                           map["Inbound_time"] ||= event.get("[Inbound][time]")
                           map["Inbound_log_level"] ||= event.get("[Inbound][log][level]")
                           map["Inbound_operation_name"] ||= event.get("[Inbound][operation][name]")
                           map["Inbound_flow"] ||= event.get("[Inbound][flow]")      
                           map["Inbound_message"] ||= event.get("[Inbound][message]")
                           map["Inbound_payload"] ||= event.get("[Inbound][payload]")
                           map["ID"] ||= event.get("ID")
                           map["Outbound_time"] ||= event.get("[Outbound][time]") 
                           map["Outbound_log_level"] ||= event.get("[Outbound][log][level]") 
                           map["Outbound_operation_name"] ||= event.get("[Outbound][operation][name]")
                           map["Outbound_flow"] ||= event.get("[Outbound][flow]")      
                           map["Outbound_message"] ||= event.get("[Outbound][message]")  
                           map["Outbound_payload"] ||= event.get("[Outbound][payload]")
                           map["event_original"] ||= event.get("[event][original]")
                           map["breadcrumbId"] ||= event.get("breadcrumbId")
                           map["BPOCO"] ||= event.get("BPOCO")
                           map["OrderID"] ||= event.get("OrderID")
                           map["QuoteID"] ||= event.get("QuoteID")
                           map["ServiceID"] ||= event.get("ServiceID")
                           map["Prodotto"] ||= event.get("Prodotto")
                           map["faultString"] ||= event.get("faultString")
                           map["Mobile/NotMobile"] ||= event.get("Mobile/NotMobile")
                           map["SOAP_action"] ||= event.get("[SOAP][action]")
                           event.cancel                                                      
        '
     push_map_as_event_on_timeout => true
     timeout => 10
      
  }
   mutate {
         copy => { "Outbound_time" => "times" }
      }
  mutate {
    convert => {"times" => "string" } 
  }
  date {
    match => ["times", "YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS"]
    target => "@timestamp"
  }  
 
}
```

Comment: code snippet or code sample is much more important here than the perfect English ;-)

Answer (score 0):

according to this source [date filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-date.html)

```
yyyy
full year number. Example: 2015.
```

and your filter is

```
date {
    match => ["times", "YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS"]
    target => "@timestamp"
  }
```

you might want to change it to

```
date {
    match => ["times", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS"]
    target => "@timestamp"
  }
```

Comment: can you copy the data of ``times`` you see from elasticsearch?

Comment: i have resolved, i have put the date plugin before the aggregate an now it works.  Thanks the same.